# Entity Framework Async vs Task.FromResult

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, task

Is there any difference between using async methods provided by System.Data.Entity from Entity Framework and wrapping the same non asynchronous methods with a Task.FromResult ?

For example :

```
    private Task<int> GetCountAsync()
    {
        return this._myDbContext.Set<MyEntity>().CountAsync();
    }
```

and

```
    private Task<int> GetCountAsync()
    {
       return Task.FromResult(this._myDbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Count());
    }
```

Comment: I saw it now, this `return Task.FromResult(this._myDbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Count());` wouldn't create a real async operation, because you're just returing a task AFTER the Count() is executed, this is one of the reason why you should never think that if there's a task there's an async operation, it depends on the implementation under the task. You should do `Task.Run(() => this._myDbContext.Set<MyEntity>().Count())` or `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it could, because if the ADO driver implements async methods using the IOCP thread pool (and it does), will not use a worker thread to wait on the operation, instead will use a special waiting mechanism using [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx), in that way, the server should be able to best scale when there's a lot of contention that do long-running operation against IO like a database query does.

Check some article you can find googling:

[I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx)

[IOCP Thread Pooling in C#](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/iocp-thread-pooling.php)

[Asynchronous Command Execution in ADO.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379553%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Took from the last link:

> In previous versions of the .NET Framework it was possible to simulate non-blocking execution by using asynchronous delegates or the ThreadPool class; however, those solutions simply blocked another thread in the background, making them far from ideal for cases where it is important to avoid blocking threads...
>
> ADO.NET/SqlClient asynchronous command execution support is based on true asynchronous network I/O under the covers (or non-blocking signaling in the case of shared memory).
>
> ...there are no blocked background threads waiting for a particular I/O operation to finish, and we use the overlapped I/O and the input/output completion ports facilities of the Windows 2000/XP/2003 operating systems to make it possible to use a single thread (or a few of them) to handle all the outstanding requests for a given process.

**Edit:** Move from comment to here to extend the answer regarding the specific problem of Async Repository Pattern:

I think you should expose those Async methods you need, extending the generic repository, avoiding to couple on EF and avoiding task wrapping, adding CountAsync, AddSync, FindAsync, and all sort of methods you need also async.

Check this out [ASYNCHRONOUS REPOSITORY PATTERN WITH ENTITY FRAMEWORK 6](http://goo.gl/5045QM)

Example of repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<int> AddAsync(T t);
    Task<int> RemoveAsync(T t);
    Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync();
    Task<int> UpdateAsync(T t);
    Task<int> CountAsync();
    Task<T> FindAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match);
    Task<List<T>> FindAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> match);
}
```

CountAsync implementation:

```
public async Task<int> CountAsync()
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<T>().CountAsync();
}
```

Directly took from the post to leave here all the contents.

Then you can extend also your generic repository.

**Edit:** added some useful readings:

- [Martin Fowler's](http://goo.gl/qw4ilW)
- [Asynchronous Repositories](http://goo.gl/iyEEhH)
- [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://goo.gl/YN1ILo)
- [The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Generic Unit of Work and Repositories (lightweight fluent) Framework with Sample Northwind ASP.NET MVC 5 Application: [**Repositories Framework**](http://goo.gl/un4bMz)

Comment: Thank you.
I ask this question, because in the architecture of my project, the dependencies from EF and System.Data.Entity are all in my data access layer, and my data access layer only exposes entities to my services layer.
So when I need to use async operations like count, max, min, etc... they are not available. 

So I found to two solutions... Use Task.FromResult in my Services Layer, or change my Data Layer to expose also the results of this kind of operations. 

I would prefer the first one, but based on your answer and on that articles it's better do the second one.

Comment: you can introduce an interface for that in the middle, then the implementation will depend on data.entity, but your code will depends only on your interface. See the [repository pattern](http://goo.gl/qw4ilW), other links: [The Repository Pattern](http://goo.gl/LklFde), [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://goo.gl/YN1ILo), [The Repository Pattern Example in C#](http://goo.gl/DDgBJV), [Repository pattern, done right](http://goo.gl/N8Zz2j)

Comment: anyway this `return this._myDbContext.Set<MyEntity>().CountAsync();` should not couple you on EF, you're just returning a Task<int>, maybe I'm not getting the problem

Comment: Yes, i'm using the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns from MVC. :D 

That's why I have this "conception" problem. 

The concept says, ideally the repositories should only expose Model Entities to the Controllers ( in my case, the Services Layer). 


Many thanks for your help Michael.

Comment: The problem is that if I want to follow the pattern, I should not expose Task<int> to my controller, only MyEntity or Task<MyEntity>. 

So in the controller, when I want to do a count, a max, a min, etc... towards to MyEntity, I cannot use the async operations provided by EF.

So my two options are, modify the pattern and return not only MyEntity from the repository, but also countings, max, min, etc... Or not violate the pattern and use Task.FromResult in the controller.

Comment: I think you should expose those Async methods you need, extending the generic repository, avoiding to couple on EF and avoiding task wrapping, adding CountAsync, AddSync, FindAsync, and all sort of methods you need also async. Check this out [ASYNCHRONOUS REPOSITORY PATTERN WITH ENTITY FRAMEWORK 6](http://goo.gl/5045QM)

Comment: Ok. And in your opinion, including subsets of <T> is a good approach to implement in the repository?

Ex : 

Task<int> CountAsync(IQuerable<T> tSubSet);
Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync(IQuerable<T> tSubSet);

This is because sometimes, the controller needs to work with a subset of data and not with the all set.

Comment: Yes I think I would prefer to pass the query to be executed instead of retrieving the IQuerable and then eventually execute the query by hitting one of the firing method (.ToList, .To*). My personal interpretation of [martin's thoughts](http://goo.gl/qw4ilW) is that you have to create a query and pass it to a function, returning the data already queried, but you know, sometimes I hate big patterns like this, because you have too many ways to achieve the same thing, just do whatever you need :) This could be interesting for you [Asynchronous Repositories](http://goo.gl/iyEEhH) yet another way!